# After installing chai, i was installing chai-webdriverio as a dev dependency but i got this error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

npm i chai-webdriverio --save-dev

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: webdriverio@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: chai@4.3.4
npm ERR! node_modules/chai
npm ERR!   dev chai@"^4.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer chai@"~4.0.1" from chai-webdriverio@1.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/chai-webdriverio
npm ERR!   dev chai-webdriverio@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by running

npm install chai-webdriverio --force

Note: Using --force makes the recommended protections to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to install the required version of chai instead :

```
npm install chai@4.0.1 --save-dev
```

Maybe this is more consistent